# Discord.py Bot Not Sending Buttons

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

My Discord.py Bot Doesn't Seem To Send The Buttons after I Enter The Command it Just Doesn't send it No Error Or Anything I've tried everything looked Up Tutorials on How To Make The Command I Tried The Tutorials Step by step Still The Bot Still doesn't Send The Button Options I Installed All Modules still Nothing The Command Basically Doesn't Work! Here's The Code Pls Help Me Find The Problem!

```
@client.command()
async def button(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Press Button", components = [Button(label="CLICK Me!")
    ]
  )
  interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("Click"))
  await interaction.respond(content="Clicked!")
```

I Just Don't know What I'm Doing Wrong. Btw My Modules are (from discord_components import *) (Note I'm Using a Phone To Develop This)

Answer (score 0):

The command seems to work for me, recheck if you have all modules correctly installed.

One thing I did notice is that the button would not work because

`interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("Click"))`
should be:
`interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("CLICK"))`
since your label has it capitalized.

Comment: I have everything perfectly installed My Only problem is When I run The Command The Bot acts like it's not a Command! No errors or anything It just doesn't work

Comment: Could you share the entire code? That way we are able to see if the bot is setup properly and has all modules

Comment: Sorry But I Asked on discord to other programmers They said they will wait for the full release of buttons